# Testing a 5- card hand for flush

Tags: python, probability, playing-cards

my goal is to get the probability of getting "flush"

here is my code:

```
from random import *

#generating deck
deck = []
for i in range(4):
    for value in range(13):
        deck.append(100*i + value)

sim = 100000


hearts = 0
spades = 0
diamonds = 0
clubs = 0

flush = 0

for i in range(sim):
  #generating hand
  hand = []
  shuffle(deck)
  for i in range(5):
    hand.append(deck[i])
  #checking for "flush"
  for i in range(5):
    if hand[i] < 100:
      hearts += 1
    elif hand[i] < 200:
      spades += 1
    elif hand[i] < 300:
      diamonds += 1
    elif hand[i] < 400:
      clubs += 1
  if hearts == 5 or spades == 5 or diamonds == 5 or clubs == 5:
    flush += 1
#probability
print(flush/sim)
```

the acutal probability is closer to 0.03 apparently but thats not what is get, is there something wrong with the logic in the code?

Comment: You never reset `hearts` and so on to zero during your simulation.

Comment: What do you get?  Also typically "four of a kind" means 4 cards of the same rank not 4 cards of the same suit: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_poker_hands#Four_of_a_kind

Comment: Four of a kind is actually having a same number in all 4 colors (ie. Having 4 nines) and not having 4 cards of the same color, so that part of the logic is also flawed

Comment: thanks, got the terminology wrong, well I mean flush

Comment: There's no need to count how many of each suit is in a hand. Just look at the suit of the first card, then check if the suit of the rest is the same. `s = hand[0] // 100; all(c // 100 == s for c in hand)`.

Comment: Also, it would be simpler to represent each card as a rank/suit pair, rather than encoding both in a single integer. This isn't C :)  `deck = [(r, s) for r in range(4) for s in range(13)]`.

Answer (score 1):

You could take advantage of the itertools module to do this:

```
from itertools import product
import random

suits = ['s', 'h', 'd', 'c']
cpips = ['2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', 'J', 'Q', 'K', 'A']

deck = [c for c in product(cpips, suits)]  # combinations of suits and values

sim = 10000
flushes = 0

for s in sim:
    random.shuffle(deck)
    hand = []
    for i in range(5):
        hand.append(deck[i])
    # check that all suits are matching
    if all([hand[0][1] == c[1] for c in hand]):
        flushes += 1

prob = flushes / sim
```

If you wanted to add some more randomness or make it more like a card game, you could create a parameter `p` for number of other players, and have `i` increase by that much after each iteration:

```
p = 5
for s in sim:
    random.shuffle(deck)
    hand = []
    while len(hand) <=5:
        hand.append(deck[i])
        i += p
    # check that all suits are matching
    if all([hand[0][1] == c[1] for c in hand]):
        flushes += 1
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you don't reset `hearts`, `clubs`, `diamonds`, `spades` back to zero in each iteration.

Your expected result of approximately 0.03 is wrong too. The probability for a flush is:

12/51 * 11/50 * 10/49 * 9/48

The probability that the second card is of the same suit as the first is 12/51 since there are 51 cards remaining in the deck and 12 of those have the same suit. With the same reasoning the probability that the third card is of the same suit is 11/50, ...etc.

This expression has a value of about 0.00198

#### Code

Your code could be simplified if you would leave out the rank part of the cards, since it plays no role in the measurement. So just produce a deck with 13 cards per suit without rank in indication.

The hand can be taken with `random.sample` and the flush check can then be done by taking the `set` of that hand: if it has size 1 then it is a flush:

```
from random import sample

sim = 100000

# generating deck with only suits
deck = [i for i in range(4) for value in range(13)]

flush = sum(1 for _ in range(sim) if len(set(sample(deck, 5))) == 1)

print(flush/sim)  # ~ 0.002
```